Scheduled Job is not running automatically In Frappe
I created a custom application in Frappe and there I registered a funtion in cron of scheduler_events in the hooks.py which has to run every minute.
now that when i migrated the job did apperead in the Scheduled Job Type and when i mannuly execute it, works perfect but it does not run automatically.
my scheduler is on for the site for which i wrote the above function.
I have searched a lot and tried every possible solutionn but I don’t know why it is not automatic.
This is my site_config.json
{
 "db_name": "",
 "db_password": "",
 "db_type": "mariadb",
 "developer_mode": 1,
 "domains": [
  {
   "domain": "",
   "ssl_certificate": "",
   "ssl_certificate_key": ""
  }
 ],
 "encryption_key": "",
 "maintenance_mode": 0,
 "scheduler_enabled": 1,
 "pause_scheduler": false
}

and the hooks.py file
scheduler_events = {
    "cron": {
        "* * * * *": [
            "my_full_function_pathh"
        ]

    }

}

I tried every possible solutions and commands but the scheduler is not automatic.
I have run this command bench --site sitename enable-scheduler and scheduler is enabled for my site but don't know why it is not automatic !
My bench version is 15.

did you ever find a solution to this? Ran into the same problem

Yeah I solved it, after so many struggle I finally refereshed my ubunutu, then installed the frappe from the very start and and then did the same process and it started working.

For me, I realised if its a new task, or if I make changes to scheduler_events in hooks.py, you have to run "bench migrate" to "register" that new task.

yeah exactly, you will have to do bench migrate in order to bring those scheduler events to database and there is a doctype called schedule job list. so you write bench migrate and you schedule job list is saved to the schedule job list table.
